# Run function when XHR finished loading (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, ratchet, push.js

I'm using the push.js library with Ratchet, which loads pages using AJAX then changes history.pushState().

I was wondering if there is any way to run a function when an XHR request has finished?

Comment: Yes, if you have access to the XHR request.

Comment: You XHR has a `success` callback. This is in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not making the XHR request, it is done as part of the page transition in push.js. I was hoping there would be some way to watch for successful XHR requests?